# list all annotations in java file - eclipse java editor

Tags: java, eclipse

Can you please let me know if there exists any possibility to list all annotations in java file opened in a eclipse editor.
For my java methods, I have specified several annotations:

```
@GetMapping("/convert")
@PostMapping("/convert")
@GetMapping("/conversionResult")
```

I am looking for view which can show me all these annotations and on double click of this annotation, selecting appropriate code.

Comment: Does _Search > Java..._ with the query `org.springframework.*.*Mapping`, search for _Type_, limit to _References_  and with the scope _Selected resources_ work for you?

Comment: Hi @howlger.. Thanks a lot for the info. As a first step search results are good.. but it is not completely satisfactory **as the search results show me list of all methods which uses these annotations**, rather than all annotation names (exmple:  `@GetMapping("/viewImage")`  is not displayed in the search result, rather method signature is displayed `public String viewImage(@RequestParam("uri") String fileURI, RedirectAttributes redirectAttribute ))`. I will be happy if you